# Sticky footer at the end of the page even if the content is small

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I can't get the footer to stick at the bottom of the page. If there is less content, i need it to be displayed without any scroll of course and if there is more content then in the end. I have the following code:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
        <div id="top_bar">
        </div>
        <div id="top_add">
            <div if="left_logo">LOGO</div>
            <div id="top_add">ADD</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="height:auto;width:100%;">
                    <div style="font-size:25px;width:90%;float:left;height:auto;">ABCD
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:10%;height:auto;float:right;">ADV.
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="foot">
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:1300px;
    min-height:100%;
}
#top_bar {
    width:100%;
    height:45px;
    min-width:1200px;
}
#top_add {
    margin-left:15px;
    height:14%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:1200px;
    min-height:130px;
}
#left_logo {
    width:215px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
#right_add {
    width:980px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
    min-width:750px;
}
#foot {
    background-color:#333333;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? When the content size is small, the property defined as max-height:100% takes the whole page and shows is empty and displays the footer in the end which is found after scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to sticky footer right, so you must be used a css position to set it fixed anywhere in the page

for bottom div add this css

```
#foot{background-color:#333333;position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;}
```

please visit live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Zsg8G/

thank you...

EDITED: hello, i found the your problems please now try this code

```
<div id='wrapper'>
        <div id="top_bar">
        </div>
        <div id="top_add">
            <div if="left_logo">LOGO</div>
            <div id="top_add">ADD</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="">
            <div>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>ABCD<br/><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:10%;height:auto;float:right;">ADV.
                    </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="push">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="foot">
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</div>

html,body{height:100%;}
#wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
}
#push,#footer{height:100px;}
```

here you must be remove the `float: left`...

live demo with: more content: http://jsfiddle.net/SCr7b/1/ and with less content: http://jsfiddle.net/HYf7q/

thank you..

Comment: I don't want it to be fixed. I need it to appear it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: ok, now click on the link and see the live demo please, there you can see the sticky footer at the bottom

Comment: you want the sticky footer at the bottom page right ?

Comment: okay if sticky means fixed then no, i am having the problem when my content is less.

Comment: means you want the footer at the bottom when even your content is less ok ?

Comment: yes and i don't want the content to overlap when it's you know more. That's why i did height:auto; in the #content so that it could take whatever height needed.

Comment: now check this here content is less and your footer is also in bottom http://jsfiddle.net/Zsg8G/6/

Comment: There is no change, are you not saving your edits? You need to update

Comment: But when i increase the content of content div, it overlaps the footer.

Comment: yes, when you give any think sticky so the content of content is overlap

Comment: hello, your problem is solved see my edit answer and visit this for live demo with more: http://jsfiddle.net/SCr7b/1/ and with less http://jsfiddle.net/HYf7q/

Comment: oh thank you, thank you so much :) update your answer so i would select it as the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Chris Braco's solution to this: http://cbracco.me/css-sticky-footer-effect/

Essentially you need to ensure there is padding below your body content to prevent an overflow under the footer, and use `position: absolute;` on the footer.

Here's your code with a working footer: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IbmiC

Let me know if you have any issues with this.

Comment: your code doesn't work if i add some more content to it